# Acessing num_rows in codeigniter and return to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

This is my Model:

```
public function fetch_customer_invoice($f_date,$t_date)
{
$this->db->select('invoice_id');
$this->db->from('invoice');
$this->db->where('date >=',$f_date);
$this->db->where('date <=',$t_date);
$res=$this->db->get();
 foreach($res->result() as $row)
 {
   $invoice=$row->invoice_id;
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('invoice_products');
   $this->db->where('invoice_id',$invoice);
   $res=$this->db->get();
   return $res->result();
 }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function fetch_customer_invoice()
{
$from_date=$this->input->post('from_date');
$to_date=$this->input->post('to_date');
$data['res']=$this->revenue_reports_model- 
  >fetch_customer_invoice($from_date,$to_date);
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Script:

```
$('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
var from_date=$("#from_date").val();
var to_date=$("#to_date").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>revenue_reports/fetch_customer_invoice/",
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'post',
    data : {"from_date" : from_date, "to_date" : to_date},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.res);
    }
  });
});
```

This query fetch all invoice id from invoice table for the particular date. From my table there are 2 rows from that particular date but, model return 1st row result only.Why??I don't know where the error is there whether it is in model or ajax function??? Pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

IN model method your `foreach` should be like this :

```
public function fetch_customer_invoice($f_date,$t_date)
{
   $this->db->select('invoice_id');
   $this->db->from('invoice');
   $this->db->where('date >=',$f_date);
   $this->db->where('date <=',$t_date);
   $res = $this->db->get();
   foreach($res->result() as $row)
   {
      $invoice=$row->invoice_id;
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('invoice_products');
      $this->db->where('invoice_id',$invoice);
      $res = $this->db->get();
      $data[] =  $res->result(); 
      /* Or better use $res->row() if only one record per id*/
  }
 return $data;
}
```

*You can use `count()` method like this :*

```
public function fetch_customer_invoice()
{
    $from_date=$this->input->post('from_date');
    $to_date=$this->input->post('to_date');
    $results = $this->revenue_reports_model->fetch_customer_invoice($from_date,$to_date);
    $data['res']= $results;
    //$data['count']= count($results);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: kk in ajax how can I get those values in for loop??

Comment: use each method in js success method like this : `$.each(data.res, function(key,value) {
  alert(value);
});`

Comment: I am using this                                                                                                    
      for (var i=0; i<data.res.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.res[i]["invoice_id"]);
       }  but in console it shows 3 undefined..why??

Comment: there are many ways to do it whichever works for u, note that ur  data may be in two loop so use another loop within first to access

Comment: without seeing ur json data structure unable to do, pls show it

Comment: [{…}]
0:{invoice_id: "SV-CI-1-07-18", product_id: "SV-CI-3-07-18-91", description: "enada", hsn_sac: "df", quantity: "4", …}
length:1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: try with this in success  : `var json =[{invoice_id: "SV-CI-1-07-18", product_id: "SV-CI-3-07-18-91", description: "enada", hsn_sac: "df", quantity: "4"}];
          $.each(json, function () {
           $.each(this, function (name, value) {
              console.log(name + '=' + value);
           });
        });`

Comment: From this how can I get particular value only like product_id and quantity

Comment: use this code to get the particular key : `var json =[{invoice_id: "SV-CI-1-07-18", product_id: "SV-CI-3-07-18-91", description: "enada", hsn_sac: "df", quantity: "4"}]; $.each(json, function () {
            console.log(this.invoice_id);
            console.log(this.quantity);
          });`